# How to check if a url (or a webservice) is alive in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, web-services, npm

How can we check if a web service or a website is alive in nodejs? I am using node version 6.11 and express. I tried using isAlive in npm, but no luck there.

This is the one I tried, but it return false all the time.

```
var IsAlive = require('is-alive');
var isAlive = new IsAlive();
isAlive.add("http://google.com", 301, function (err) {
    "use strict";

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

setInterval(function () {
    console.log(isAlive.isAlive("http://google.com"));
}, 2000);

console.log(isAlive.isAlive("http://google.com"));
```

I use using http as well like :

```
    http.get('http://google.com', function (res) {
console.log(res);

}).on('error', function(e) {
 console.log(e);

});;
```

And also like :

```
    var request = require('request');
    options = {method: 'HEAD', host: 'stackoverflow.com', port: 80, path: '/'},
    req = http.request(options, function(r) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(r.headers));
    });
req.end();
```

Tried using status code as well  :

```
var http = require("http");
http.get({host: "google.com"},function(res){
    if (res.statusCode ==200)
        console.log ("running");
        else 
console.log ("not running");


});
```

Can we use any other method? basically my requirement is to check if a web service which is on a different server.

Comment: Can't you just check the http status codes?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle could you please elaborate? I tried using http as well(please see the edited question). But that is not working as well. While I debug the console is logging anything.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I am new to stack over flow, and I can't even upvote the answers. pardon me if I am wrong, but kindly do help.

Comment: can you set it answered @Amal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I cracked this. The problem as I doubt was since I was behind a proxy. So I modified the code given by @turmuka like :

```
   var request = require('request');

    var link = "https://nodejs.org/";

    var proxyUrl = "http://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port;

var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': proxyUrl});

  proxiedRequest(link , function (error, response, body) {

      if(error){
        console.log('Err: '+ error);
        return false;
      }

    if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202){
      console.log(link + ' is up!!');
      return false;
    }

    if(response.statusCode == 301 || response.statusCode == 302){
      console.log(link + ' is redirecting us!!');
      return false;
    }

    if(response.statusCode == 401){
      console.log("you are unauthorized to " + link);
      return false;
    }else{
      console.log(link + ' is down!!');
    }

    });
```

So basically, I need to set the proxy in the request to make sure the proxy won't be blocking the call. 
Thank you very much @turmuka for the  answer, really helped me to figure it out.

Comment: Awesome job! I knew it'd be about *proxy credentials*. Glad you made it and I was some help @Amal

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a small program for you, this program extracts data from https://isitdownorjust.me/ it checks if a website is up or down.

I have tested it, the website is not 100% stable sometimes, but the program works fine.

Here is the code

```
var request = require('request');

var website = "stackoverflow",
    ext = "com";



request('https://isitdownorjust.me/'+ website +'-' + ext + '/', function (error, response, body) {

  if(error){
    console.log('Err: '+ error);
    return false;
  }

  if(body.match('seems to be working.')){
    console.log(website + '.' +ext+' is up according to isitdownorjust.me');
  }else{
    console.log(website + '.' +ext+"the website is down according to isitdownorjust.me");
  }

});
```

**USAGE**

All you have to do is put the website name there and it's extension to bottom. You don't have to use `.` (dot)

Hope you like it..

**UPDATE**

With using plain Node JS module

```
var request = require('request');

var link = "https://nodejs.org/";



request(link , function (error, response, body) {

  if(error){
    console.log('Err: '+ error);
    return false;
  }

if(response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201 || response.statusCode == 202){
  console.log(link + ' is up!!');
  return false;
}

if(response.statusCode == 301 || response.statusCode == 302){
  console.log(link + ' is redirecting us!!');
  return false;
}

if(response.statusCode == 401){
  console.log("you are unauthorized to " + link);
  return false;
}else{
  console.log(link + ' is down!!');
}

});
```

Just use the `link` variable.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that

Comment: Because it's fun? What's that reaction? @NicoVanBelle

Comment: Thank you, but could you please confirm if we can use it without an external site, simply hitting the required web address?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I would prefer a usual method without an external website, as mainly I need this for webservices. So using other websites are not that preferred.

Comment: @turmuka time out error. Debug is stuck at 
request(link , function (error, response, body) and it finally gives out a timeout error, not sure why. :(

Comment: what is the link that you're using? @Amal

Comment: are you sure? it work perfectly fine for me? try downloading `request` module again, and make sure to add `https://` in front. You are using the second piece of code right?

Comment: @turmuka yes the second piece of code. you mean request using npm install right?
basically I copied your code and then run it using node nodejs.js. haven't modified/added/deleted anything.

Comment: yes use `npm install request` when you are at the directory where this file is located, make sure the link is exactly `https://nodejs.org/` and then do `node youfile.js` @Amal let me know!

Comment: getting error like : Err: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.223.36:443
Not sure what the reason is. I am behind a corporate proxy, will that be an issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153093/discussion-between-amal-and-turmuka).